# Ajax repainting component stops loading Javascripts

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

I have a wicket form  - when I click submit - its shows me the dynamic table from the database - 
I want the table to be sortable - so I used listview repeater and table sorttable.js 
to able to sort the table.

Now when I refreash the page - I have the sorting capability available - 
but when I click submit - I can't sort the table

```
       wmc.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model("sorttable"), ";"));
       wmc.add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", new Model("sorttable()"), ";"));

       <table class="sortable" wicket:id="someContainer">
```

Is there any way - where I can reload my sorttable.js - while ajax repaint is done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem here is that sorttable.js (at least the version I found) is not realy intended for this. You do can attach javascript calls to the end of an Ajax call. See my result [at github](https://github.com/taseroth/WicketNamedTabs/tree/master/src/main/java/org/faboo/test/pages/sorttable).

Basically, you need to add this to the AjaxSubmitLink that reloads the ListView:

```
target.appendJavaScript("sorttable.init();");
```

The only remaining problem is that sorttable.js somehow prevents itself from being run twice. So I needed to comment out the

```
if (arguments.callee.done)
```

check in the init() function. My knowledge of javascript is rather limited. If you know a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Works like charm - you are great - thanks a lot - 

but I think I have to move to datatable anyway - 

having problem with - passing arguments in model to filter DB queries ... 

Should I use DB table  ? or this solution is ok ?

Comment: If you need filtering, pagination,.. I would devinately go with a more advanced Wicket component. I just wanted to learn something myself about the javascript integration in Wicket, so I had a go at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure for 100 % but I think it is not possible to reload also the javascript within or triggered by this ajax call.

I would use the `DefaultDataTable` component provided by the wicket framework. It comes with building support for sorting.

Comment: yea - that is the way to go I guess  but before changing everything I want to give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

when you insert some javascript that its executed on document ready(jquery stuff) you must re attach that events when you apply changes to your DOM, you can do it as bert told, or overwriting the method called [renderHead](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-ComponentimplementsIHeaderContributorandBehaviorhas%2523renderHead%2528Component%252CIHeaderResponse%2529),

wathever wicket implements a table with order via ajax see http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/repeater/

Comment: thanks for the pointer - :) 
I think I have to move to Datatable eventually .. :-/

Comment: wicket have a lot of stuff ready to use, search a little before implements things